# Selection of Global or Local Data source in presentation details

Tags: presentation, datasource

[image: Footer Component]

**Selection of Data Sources in Presentation Details :**

- There are two data sources for the footer component , one at the
  local repository level and another in the Global Content level.

  While choosing the data source for the footer rendering in the
  presentation details , **how can we show the Global and Local data
  items.** as explained in the below image.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple:

Your datasource location (which you need to define in the Footer Rendering Item) will look like below:

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Home Item Templatye Name']/Global Content/Footer Global Contetn|./Footer Local Content
```

You need to correct paths and Home page template name.

See this article: http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-rendering-datasource-locations/

Basically there are a simple Sitecore queries in the paths above and the parameters can be different. You can read detailed about sitecore queries by the following link or google something like "Sitecore query" for building another queries:

http://sitecoreworld.blogspot.com.by/2014/09/querying-items-from-sitecore.html:

Comment: @Sandeep Did it help you?